# Floating image to the right corner of heading

Tags: html, css

So the issue I am having is that I want the image to be in the upper right corner of the div but on the same line/level as the title. Right now it is just staying next to the title and with padding or margin it just pushes the title over. If anyone knows how to fix this that would be super helpful! Thank you!

```css
#whoheading{
    color:#10D0C9;
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    display:flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    justify-content: center;     
}

#description{
    display:flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #BBBBBB;
    margin:15px;
    max-width: 1000px;
}

#smaller {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-self: center;      
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#whoperson{
    width:100px;     
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:20px;     
}
```

```html
<div id="who">      
    <h3 id="whoheading">Who Am I? <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/4BNnZN8pRM2FMCzZo_JRm3v17wi1bu2fCI4lCVw9R-ASyS0O1uPUviBLAsC_-NiWLCE=w300" id="whoperson"></h3>      
    <div id="smaller">
        <p id="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
    </div>      
    <a href="about.html" id="whogoal" class="goals hover-fill" data-txthover="Hover Over Me">Get to know me better</a>      
    <div class="keepOpen"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would surround the image and `h3` element with a `div` and apply some styling to that div to get the effect that you are looking for.

See below:

```css
#top{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#whoheading{
  color:#10D0C9;
  font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 65px;
}

#whoperson{
  width:100px;
  margin:20px;
  float: right;
}

#description{
  display:flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #BBBBBB;
  margin:15px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

#smaller {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-self: center;      
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="who">  
  <div id="top">
    <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/4BNnZN8pRM2FMCzZo_JRm3v17wi1bu2fCI4lCVw9R-ASyS0O1uPUviBLAsC_-NiWLCE=w300" id="whoperson">
    <h3 id="whoheading">Who Am I?</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="smaller">
      <p id="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
  </div>      
  <a href="about.html" id="whogoal" class="goals hover-fill" data-txthover="Hover Over Me">Get to know me better</a>      
  <div class="keepOpen"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU @spencer.sm this made perfect sense and really helped me figure out this problem. Thank you! You are very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. put floating image first then type the text  like
   image link style=float:right...then

Who Am I?

2. make Carring DIV width 100%

Answer (score 0):

try these css:

```
#whoheading {
   align-items: flex-start;
}

#whoperson {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```